# Integral operator

Tags: functional-analysis

Let T: $C[0,1]\rightarrow C[0,1]$ be defined by 
$y(t)=\int_{0}^{t}x(\tau)d\tau$. Find Img(T).

I know that $\text{Img}(T)=\{w\in C[0,1]:w=T(y(t)) \text{ for some } t\in C[0,1]\}$.

Could you give me any suggestions?

Comment: Use the fact that $f=\int f'$ to show that the image is the space of $C^1$ functions.

Comment: It should be "for some $y \in C[0,1]$" right? Also the definition of $T$ is not very clear, I assume you mean $(Ty)(t)  = \int_0^t y(\tau)d\tau$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What can you say about the $\mathcal{C}^1$ functions that are 0 at 0?